# Preventing subclasses from adding methods

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

This might seem like an odd thing to want, but is there a way in Java to stop subclasses from adding new methods (including constructors) whilst still allowing subclasses to override methods?

The actual situation is where we have an `abstract` class with some abstract methods and a constructor

```
abstract class A {
  abstract A doX();
  abstract boolean isY();
  public A(String s){ ... };
}
```

and we want all concrete subclasses of this class to only override these methods and constructor.

This is about enforcing a certain style in our code i.e. stopping other people working on the code from adding things. We could just tell them not to, but that rarely works, so we wondered if there was a programmatic way of achieving this.

Obviously the class cannot be `final`. Efficiency isn't paramount - cleaner code is more important.

**Update - dynamic approach**

As has been pointed out in the answers, there is no way to do this statically as the only way to prevent subclasses being created is using `final`, which won't work. But I could use a dynamic approach so my current solution is to add this `aspect` to the project (which already uses `AspectJ`).

```
   public aspect WatchA{
      before() : execute(* A.*()) || execute(* A.*(..)) {
         String methodCalled = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
         Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0])
         Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
         boolean found = false;
         for(Method m : allMethods)
           found |= m.getName().equals(methodCalled);
         if(!found) 
           throw new RuntimeException("Do not add method "+methodCalled+" to A");
      }
   }
```

Which will cause their tests to fail if they use any of these new methods.

Comment: Java doesn't allow this. Better to introduce a rigorous code-review policy.

Comment: By curiosity, why is final forbidden?

Comment: I want subclasses to be able to override methods but not add them - so we need to be able to create subclasses. I understand that this is all very over-subscribed and to be honest I'm now mainly just interested whether it can be done - I think we'll end up going with the "tell them not to" approach.

Comment: i agree you should just tell them not to. I would hate to be in that team if I was forced to un-learn basic OO inheritance.

Comment: Just as a side note, if the API is complete, implementations should not see the _need_ to add anything on their own, should they?

Comment: Why does it matter if they add additional methods? I'm assuming that within your part of the application you refer to them as being instances of the parent class? If they have other methods your part of the application will never know. (I'm not saying its unreasonable to want this, but knowing why can shed light on how)

Comment: Also; to provide the functionality of overridding some of the parent classes the child class may want some (probably private) methods that break the overridden method into pieces (or be re-used between several overridden methods). Is this also to be forbidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wan't to do this.. one way would be to programatically check in the abstract class constructor that the methods defined in the class are those that are allowed.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public abstract class Base {

    private static final Set<String> allowedMethodNames = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("doThis", "wait", "wait", "wait", "equals", "toString", "hashCode", "getClass", "notify", "notifyAll"));

    public Base() {
        Set<String> allMethods = new HashSet<>();
        for (Method aMethod : getClass().getMethods()) {
            allMethods.add(aMethod.getName());
        }
        if (!allowedMethodNames.equals(allMethods)) {
            allMethods.removeAll(allowedMethodNames);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Following methods not allowed <" + allMethods + ">");
        }
    }

    public abstract void doThis();
}

public class Disallowed extends Base {

    @Override
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("dooooooo");
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println("not allowed");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Allowed().doThis();
        new Disallowed();
    }

}

public class Allowed extends Base {

    @Override
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("doing this");
    }


}
```

When someone is trying create an instance of 'Disallowed' it would fail. However 'new Allowed().doThis()' will work fine.

A more graceful way to do this would be to introduce a custom annotation + annotation processor and do the same check during the compilation time.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do that. Only if classes are `final` can you ensure that no subclass can be created.

You can also make *methods* final (even in abstract classes) so that overriding them is forbidden.

Your best bet is to create an interface, with all methods you want visible, and force all users of your API to access the objects via this interface. This way, even if implementations add their own stuff, said stuff won't be visible.

One solution for this is to implement a factory to return the concrete classes; for "added security", you could put all implementations in the same package as this factory and make constructors package local (but this is often not practical):

```
public final class MyFactory
{
    // ....
    public MyInterface getConcrete()
    {
        return new MyInterfaceImpl();
    }
    // etc etc -- getStones(), getTar(), getFeathers() and so on
}
```

Note that builders can also be used for that.

Comment: How is this an answer to "stop subclasses from adding new methods"? besides the OP doesn't want to prevent subclasses from overriding parent methods.He wants them not to add their own methods other than what is defined in parent. Java fan boys every where

Comment: @srikanthyaradla This is about "stop subclasses from adding new methods" -- the first 4 words of it: "You cannot do that". And then I propose an alternative. What is the problem?

Comment: You could have just stopped there. But you said "One solution for this is to implement a factory to return the concrete classes" which doesnt  prevent the implementing classes from adding their own methods.

Comment: @srikanthyaradla read the post again. This allows the users of the API to have access to only what is required. Implementations can add all the crap they want; they can even phone to Jupiter for all it matters.

Comment: This goes no where. " Implementations can add all the crap they want; they can even phone to Jupiter for all it matters" But OP does not want that. You could have done the same using parent abstract reference. This is not any different from Using interface. Now lets not continue debating abstract vs interface

Comment: Well sure it goes nowhere, but your initial comment led to that, basically.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way.
Why would you want to enforce such a coding style?

If you really must enforce such a style you could create a "rule enforcer" which checks your classpath and compares the methods of your abstract parent classes with their sub classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is Java which means flexibility. So java gives you more convinient in using the abstract methods and overriding them from your subclasses. Also one should have an idea of adding new methods to these subclasses. Even java can't change this. If it does then the whole Java community crash. It is impossible that you can prevent from adding methods to their subclasses. Only you can stop them extending your classes and overridding your methods.